# Why am I unable to find a record by _id in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, find, auto-increment

I am trying to find a record in mongoDB by it's MongoID "_id" field.   I have found examples on how to do it, but can not get it to work. Example:

```
$recID = "010101010101011";  //would be a valid mongodb _id
$recID = new MongoId((string)$recID);  // I have tried it without the (string) cast too
$cursor = $this->Collection->findOne(array('_id' => $recID));
print_r($cursor);
```

It outputs:

```
MongoCursor (
)
```

Nothing inside.

I have verified everything else is working by changing the "_id" above to a different field such as "firstName" and passing in a first name and I get back valid data.

Why does this not work?

I have even tried searching with $recID as a string, no difference.

Here is what happens from the mongo shell (though I am not sure if I am querying properly):

```
>
> db.Employee.find({login:"myperson"})
{ "_explicitType" : "project.Employee", "_id" : ObjectId("4e209564203d83940f0000
06"), "active" : true, "addedDate" : "07/15/2011 15:29:21", "domain" : "xxx",
 "id" : ObjectId("4e209564203d83940f000006"), "lastLogin" : "07/20/2011 19:13:36
", "login" : "myperson", "name" : "My Person", "pw" : "", "ulevel" : 9999
}
> db.Employee.find({id:"4e209564203d83940f000006"})
> db.Employee.find({_id:"4e209564203d83940f000006"})
>
```

Notice nothing returned for id or _id.

Comment: Can you find it using mongodb interactive shell?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try `db.Employee.find({_id:ObjectId("4e209564203d83940f000006")}`

Comment: Ok, that works from the shell, but it's not working from php using my code above.

Comment: So I reviewed my php code again and it's working now.  I have no idea why.  It was good learning about the mongodb shell though.

Answer (score 4):

you can wrap your id around a ObjectID wrapper.  This tells mongo db your looking for a specific column the _id column.

```
var ObjectID=require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

then do

```
collection.findOne({_id: ObjectID(id)},function(err,user){  //blah blah}
```