# Can not find a record by it's _id in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to get a record by its `_id` like this:

```
db.user.find({_id : ObjectId("53a095aa4568cb1fef93f681")})
```

As you can see the record exists:

[image: mongoDB record by _id]

I think my way is correct according to:

- [Why am I unable to find a record by _id in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867388/why-am-i-unable-to-find-a-record-by-id-in-mongodb)
- [how do I search for an object by its ObjectId in the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233014/how-do-i-search-for-an-object-by-its-objectid-in-the-console)
- [Is it ok to use Mongo's "Object ID" as its unique identifier? If so, how can I convert it to a string and look it up by string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176692/is-it-ok-to-use-mongos-object-id-as-its-unique-identifier-if-so-how-can-i-c)

So what's wrong with my code? I'm using RoboMongo.

Comment: As answered below you inserted your documents without using the default MongoDB ObjectId type, probably a bug in your code or something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `_id` field isn't an `ObjectId` it is just a String.

This should work:

`db.user.find({_id : "53a095aa4568cb1fef93f681"})`

Mongodocs: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/ObjectId/

Comment: OMG! What a silly mistake I've made! Waste of my time for hours :|
Thanks buddy...

Comment: Well ... how many hours I have spend with stupid mistakes where mongodb was involved...

Comment: @Zarathustra,  why i have documents with string and sometimew with object, i remember i've had some of record with a GUI, but i dont remember well, anyway where i can set that, and what is the best option ?

Comment: @stackdave to use the autogenerated ObjectId. You may find the documents where _id is a string by a query. You may learn something from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30975037/1248724

Answer (score 4):

If you are using python, Try this,

```
from bson import ObjectId
db.user.find({_id : ObjectId("53a095aa4568cb1fef93f681")})
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometime it is right to find _id as a str, sometime it is right to find _id as an ObjectId, it depends on where you are.

a. NoSQLBooster/Pymongo:

```
db.user.find({_id : ObjectId("53a095aa4568cb1fef93f681")})
```

b. Robo3T/RoboStudio

```
db.user.find({_id : "53a095aa4568cb1fef93f681"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```js
{ _id: new ObjectId('53a095aa4568cb1fef93f681')
```

It is what worked for me. Try adding `new ObjectID('53a095aa4568cb1fef93f681').`
It gave me error without using new. Hope that helps